# Is it possible to create MultiPolygon mask using turf?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl, turfjs

I'm trying to create mask for MultiPolygon area using another MultiPolygon using this example http://turfjs.org/docs/#mask

As a result of:

```
masked = turf.mask(multiPolygon1, multiPolygon2);
```

I get error:

```
npmcdn.com/@turf/turf@4.2.0/turf.min.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coordinates' of undefined
    at s (https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf@4.2.0/turf.min.js:18:24640)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The mask API doesn't accept a MultiPolygon for its second parameter. ( http://turfjs.org/docs/#mask ) You can only pass a Polygon.

A workaround solution is:

1. Split your MultiPolygon mask into an array of Polygons.
2. Then loop for each Polygon in your array call mask() passing that Polygon to the second parameter, and save the result in a variable.
3. In a second loop, use intersect() to combine all the mask results from step 2 into one result.

Comment: I would love to see an example of this! I'm trying to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library ([JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts)) which is able to mask complex polygons. It works with `geometries` and not with Geojson though.

```
const complexGeometry = JSON.parse('{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[102,2],[103,2],[103,3],[102,3],[102,2]]],[[[100,0],[101,0],[101,1],[100,1],[100,0]],[[100.2,0.2],[100.2,0.8],[100.8,0.8],[100.8,0.2],[100.2,0.2]]],[[[100.3,0.3],[100.7,0.3],[100.7,0.7],[100.3,0.7],[100.3,0.3]],[[100.4305160192801,0.67817296142852],[100.42176614977494,0.6777431305923907],[100.41310055071305,0.6764577778174132],[100.40460268077847,0.6743292824257617],[100.39635438296318,0.6713781440787653],[100.38843509621175,0.667632785305691],[100.3809210902431,0.6631292777150927],[100.37388473092459,0.6579109945286342],[100.36739378327755,0.6520281927874465],[100.36151075883018,0.6455375292587178],[100.35629231360264,0.6385015147088778],[100.35178870252209,0.6309879118031904],[100.34804329551801,0.6230690824341718],[100.34509215995416,0.6148212907677792],[100.34296371341229,0.6063239687221135],[100.34167845016515,0.5976589509544159],[100.34124874396572,0.5889096867249723],[100.34167872904445,0.5801604362283926],[100.34296426045371,0.5714954591315431],[100.34509295413531,0.56299820313176],[100.34804430631903,0.5547505003481902],[100.35178989109856,0.5468317792832317],[100.35629363427834,0.5393182999407915],[100.36151216085236,0.5322824194649319],[100.3673952127673,0.5257918953685367],[100.37388613294743,0.5199092330597317],[100.38092241092006,0.5146910839473947],[100.38843628478985,0.5101876999202546],[100.39635539376593,0.5064424494514895],[100.40460347496123,0.503491399987565],[100.41310109775573,0.5013629706420072],[100.42176642865488,0.5000776585380188],[100.4305160192801,0.49964784143480295],[100.43926560990533,0.5000776585380188],[100.4479309408045,0.5013629706420072],[100.45642856359898,0.503491399987565],[100.46467664479428,0.5064424494514895],[100.47259575377038,0.5101876999202546],[100.48010962764015,0.5146910839473947],[100.48714590561279,0.5199092330597317],[100.4936368257929,0.5257918953685365],[100.49951987770788,0.5322824194649319],[100.50473840428187,0.5393182999407914],[100.50924214746165,0.5468317792832317],[100.51298773224117,0.5547505003481902],[100.51593908442491,0.56299820313176],[100.51806777810651,0.5714954591315431],[100.51935330951578,0.5801604362283926],[100.51978329459449,0.5889096867249723],[100.51935358839506,0.5976589509544159],[100.51806832514795,0.6063239687221135],[100.51593987860606,0.6148212907677792],[100.5129887430422,0.6230690824341719],[100.50924333603814,0.6309879118031904],[100.50473972495757,0.6385015147088778],[100.49952127973005,0.6455375292587178],[100.49363825528266,0.6520281927874464],[100.48714730763562,0.6579109945286341],[100.48011094831709,0.6631292777150927],[100.47259694234847,0.667632785305691],[100.46467765559704,0.6713781440787653],[100.45642935778174,0.6743292824257617],[100.44793148784716,0.6764577778174132],[100.43926588878527,0.6777431305923907],[100.4305160192801,0.67817296142852]]],[[[101.2,0.2],[101.8,0.2],[101.8,0.8],[101.2,0.8],[101.2,0.2]],[[101.3,0.3],[101.3,0.7],[101.7,0.7],[101.7,0.3],[101.3,0.3]]]]}')

const coverGeometry = JSON.parse('{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-180,-90],[180,-90],[180,90],[-180,90],[-180,-90]]]}')

const reader = new jsts.io.GeoJSONReader();
const writer = new jsts.io.GeoJSONWriter();
const coverJsts = reader.read(coverGeometry)
const complexGeometryJsts = reader.read(complexGeometry)
const difference = jsts.operation.overlay.OverlayOp.difference(coverJsts, complexGeometryJsts)
const result = writer.write(difference)
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

If you want to get the `geometry` of a GeoJSON, you can use turf's [getGeom](https://turfjs.org/docs/#getGeom)()